# Create shoutbox(chat room) in liferay by using primepush

Tags: primefaces, liferay, liferay-6, chatroom

I would like to create a shoutbox(or chat room) to my community, so any solution for that ?

**Demo image:**

[image]

Thank in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a PrimeFaces Ajax Push demo portlet contributed that can be found at issue [FACES-1421](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-1421). It doesn't demonstrate chat, but does demonstrate the Ajax Push mechanism required for chat. The [icefaces3-chat-portlet](http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/demos#icefaces3-chat-portlet) would be a good place to start for developing such a portlet.

Comment: Thank for your attention, your suggestion can chat between only two user, chat room is what i need :)

Comment: The original version of the icefaces3-chat-portlet that I mentioned contained a chat room type of feature but it has since been refactored to look like the out-of-the box Liferay chat portlet. I would recommend that you look at some of the [chat room Java classes](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-faces/tree/3.1.0-ga1/demos/portal/icefaces3-chat-portlet/src/main/java/com/liferay/faces/demos/dto) in that version.

Comment: hi Neil Griffin, i have tested with Primefaces chat and it work fine in jsf project, but when i create portlet, it doesn't work, please guess me some suggestions, thank you :)

Comment: We have it on our roadmap to develop a primefaces3-ipc-ajax-push-portlet (See issue [FACES-1387](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-1387)) but development has not started. Some developers in the Liferay Forums have had some success though. See this [forum post](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/22194466#_19_message_15552245) for more info.

Comment: Thank Neil very much, i have created successful my own shoutbox(by followwing your answers and comments on liferay's forum) :)

Comment: My pleasure -- so glad to hear that it is working for you. :)